# Hardware Configuration of Sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me with a tsql script which outputs the hardware configuration of sql server?

Comment: What hardware information do you need to know? RAM, CPU, DISKS, O/S version... etc?

Comment: @Kane everything including RAM, CPU, DISKS, OS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you some stuff:

```
exec xp_msver
GO
```